# Compiling GWT with ANT

Tags: java, jenkins, gwt, ant

Good Morning to every one.

I have a GWT application thath uses ANT for compile.

I am trying to configure the APP on a Jenkins server, but when I start the ANT task to compile, I receive this error:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 [java] Could not find the main class: .  Program will exit.
  [antcall] Exiting /var/quark/repositories/jenkins/workspace/AMSSISAL-NEW_CLS_FRONTEND/build.xml.
```

In my local PC, I can compile with no problems.

The most strange thing, is on the error, I can't see the ClassName. Normally in this kind of errors you can see "Could not find the main class: packageName/ClassName.  Program will exit." but in the log I only see a WhiteSpace instead of the Class name. Anybody knows why this can happen?

EDIT: This is my ANT Task for compile  :

```
<target name="gwtc"depends="javac"description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
<parallel threadsperprocessor="1">
    <java failonerror="true"fork="true"classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelementlocation="src"/>
            <pathrefid="project.class.path"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xms5120M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx10240M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:PermSize=128m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=80"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=95"/>
        <jvmarg value="-verbose:gc"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+UseCompressedOops"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+UseParNewGC"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:+AggressiveOpts"/>
        <jvmarg value="-server"/>
        <arg value="-logLevel"/>
        <arg value="ERROR"/>
        <arg value="-style"/>
        <arg value="OBF"/>
        <arg value="-optimize"/>
        <arg value="9"/>
        <arg value="-localWorkers"/>
        <arg value="4"/>
        <arg value="my.GWT.module"/>
    </java>
</parallel>
```

Comment: I hope you are in the correct directory while running `ant`. If not try to go to there in script and then run this again.

Comment: Please show us how your build.xml file is trying to run the GWT compiler.

Comment: Hi. I will check the Jenkins ant running directory.

I have poste de Ant task for compile GWT.

Comment: Hi. I have added the parameter "-Dbasedir" to ANT to point the correct directory, but the problem remains.

Comment: The question is not HOW, but WHY?

Comment: Sorry Luigi, I don't understand you

Comment: Why do you have a single task inside a parallel block?

Comment: I recently have inherited this app from another provider. I don't know why.

Comment: I think that is problem of the Jenkins Ant installation, because the project compile with no problem in two different PC with two different ant installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the ANT log I see that one of the `<jvmarg>` are a empty string. 
This provoke that between two of the parameters are two blank spaces.

On windows there is no problem with this, but on linux (With Open JDK and Oracle JDK) the params are cutted in the double space and the rest of the command is ignored after the spaces.

So, the class is not passed as a param, this is the reason of the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" don't print the class name, beacuse really, ant are trying to load and empty class in the classloader:

```
ClassLoader.loadClass("");
```

This provokes the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```